# Highchart wrapping category labels

Tags: highcharts

In an horizontal bar chart, label are cropped instead of wrapping

[image]

I'm using

```
xAxis: { 
    categories: ['Holds regular team meetings for passing on information and sharing opinions',
    'Implements and strictly adheres to work safety rules',
    'Makes clear what he/she expects of me and sets clear goals',
    'Maintains focus in ambiguous and pressure situations',
    'Takes an interest in his/her workers and is attentive to their needs',
    'Initiates processes of improvement increased efficiency and cost reduction',
    'Promotes collaboration with other units',
    'Expresses recognition and appreciation for a job well done',
    'Allocates time teaching and coaching',
    'Gives me feedback on my performance',
    'Promotes my personal and professional development',
    'Creates enthusiasm among his subordinates',
    'Encourages people to take the initiative and widen their scope of responsibility',
    'Effectively delegates tasks and authority'],
    labels: {
        step: '1',
        style: {
            lineHeight: '10%',
            color: 'red',
            fontSize: '13px'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable ellipsis by setting `textOverflow: 'none'`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ybrp5z1e/

Comment: It works almost well except that when there is a mixture of long an short labels, I get no aligned categories